# JUCE ios audio processing

Tags: ios, audio, juce

Could you point me to any examples where JUCE library has been used process Audio in iOS. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Waruna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the JUCE demo included with JUCE. This runs just fine on iOS. Just edit that code and register an `AudioIODeviceCallback` with your `AudioDeviceManager` object to do some custom audio processing.

Comment: I know this demos are working, but if I add JUCE to existing projects, is there a specific way to add modules. Because when I just add them using add files to Xcode project. IT generates errors, related to finding files. But My header search paths etc are correct.

Comment: Yes, but it seems it worst. It don't see any option in Intorjucer to create a iOS Xcode Project, but after creating a Mac Xcode project. When I try to iOS project. By Adding necessary frameworks and deleting unwanted ones. It give about 40 Apple Mach-O Linker errors.

Comment: The introjucer will allow you to make iOS projects and will add all necessary frameworks for you. When was the last time you pulled in the JUCE tip over git and rebuilt the introjucer?